# How can I stop a for loop from console.log every iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to accomplish the following:

consider an array of integers of size N. You should find and print the position of all the elements with value X. You can choose the variables and values.

Here are my variables:

```
var numLocation = [];
var givenNum = 8;
var arr = [0,8,1,2,4,5,7,8,9,0,8]
```

This is my function

```
function indexPosition(arr) {
  for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] === givenNum) {
    numLocation.push(i)
    } else {
      console.log (numLocation)
    }
  }
 }
```

This is my result after calling the function:

```
[]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1,7]
[1,7]
[1,7,10]
```

How do I only show the last iteration where it shows the three positions where the number 8 is located at? Meaning, How can I console.log only the final result?

Comment: Put the `console.log` after your for loop..  basically before the last `}`

Comment: Putting the `console.log()` outside of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the log statement outside of your for loop. Like so:

```
function indexPosition(arr, givenNum) {
  var numLocation = []

  for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === givenNum) {
      numLocation.push(i)
    }
  }

  console.log(numLocation)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alex, this is great!